# How can you protect info contained in an APK?

Tags: java, android, apk

I assume someone's built an APK decompiler.....  What's the best practice to secure sensitive info (like auth parameters for a backend database)?  I suppose some kind of middleware would work but that can't do good things for speed.  What's the "right way"?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the right way is always "don't trust the client".

Comment: I'm definitely on board with that policy.  So if you're hitting something that requires username/password that you don't want the client to ever glean from your APK, what's the best way to obfuscate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to reverse-engineer Dalvik byte code; my understanding is that there's not a simple mapping back to Java byte code, much less to Java source, particularly if it's gone through ProGuard. **However**, auth parameters are usually data, not code, and that can be snooped for rather more easily. Moreover, someone interested in breaking your credentials has lots of other means of attack, including packet sniffing, that don't require recovering your source code. The comment by Anon is exactly right—don't trust the client.

As to best practices, you can use a public key encryption system, get credentials from the server, etc., to avoid putting sensitive info into the .apk file. Don't trust obfuscation or obscure byte code to keep your secrets. They won't.

Comment: Thanks Ted.  Unfortunately, I don't own the server so there's only so much I can do but there are some security options (like creating users, key rotation, etc) that I'll pursue.  Understand snooping will happen but I wish there was a way to completely encrypt certain parts of the source.  From what I've read, it's not too hard to walk an .apk back to the actual code.  If someone else knows more, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing an Andoid app and using AWS, strongly recommend you check out:

https://github.com/apetresc/awskeyserver

Author uses the AWS IAM (Identity and Access Management service) with Google App Engine to successfully protect authentication parameters.  I imagine IAM will eventually be included in AWS' Android SDK but until then, this is a great option.